# Set HTML content of a SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint

I have a Team Site and I try to modify a page in it programmatically. This code adds a web part to the page:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://myserver"))
{
    using (var web = site.OpenWeb("/test16"))
    {

        foreach(var l in web.Lists)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("list : " + l);
        }

        SPList list = web.Lists["Shared Documents"];
        // Instantiate the web part
        ListViewWebPart wp = new ListViewWebPart();
        wp.ZoneID = "Left";
        wp.ListName = list.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();
        wp.ViewGuid = list.DefaultView.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();

        SPFile file = web.GetFile("/test16/SitePages/Home.aspx");
        SPLimitedWebPartManager lwpm = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);
        SPLimitedWebPartCollection webParts = lwpm.WebParts;
        lwpm.AddWebPart(wp, "Left", 0);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
Console.ReadLine();
```

How do I modify the HTML content of the page?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a LiteralControl to your web part and fill it with HTML like this:

`this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br /"));`

Comment: Ok, thanks, that could work, but I'm sure there must be a way to edit Home.aspx file directly.

Comment: Just have a look [here](http://blog.sharepointelearning.com/site-level-customizations-and-settings-using-sharepoint-designer-2010/)

Answer (score 0):

Try [SPFile.CheckOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms454425.aspx) and [SPFile.CheckIn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms467428.aspx):

```
SPFile file = web.GetFile("/test16/SitePages/Home.aspx");
file.CheckOut();
using (SPLimitedWebPartManager lwpm = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared))
{
    try
    {
        SPLimitedWebPartCollection webParts = lwpm.WebParts;
        lwpm.AddWebPart(wp, "Left", 0);
    }
    finally
    {
        lwpm.Web.Dispose();
    }
}       
file.CheckIn("checkin");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to modify pure HTML content, its better to use cutom IHttpHandler (wrapped in dll) and connect it to SharePoint via web.config. Is is also allowing to modify dynamic content like AJAX responses.